# Django: how to stop Django from altering filenames (e.g. transforming a space into a _ )?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a little Django project and I have a filefield in my models.py.
Everything works fine, but I don't like that Django is editing the filenames after upload. It changes spaces into underscores and it removes (square) brackets and stuff like that.

Is there any way to stop Django from doing this?
I can see that it is to make the website safer, more secure and also just avoid errors. But, I'm the only one who's going to be able to upload files anyway.

Hopefully someone knows if (and how) this is possible :)

Thanks!

edit:

Here's the FileField in the models.py:

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to=file_path)
```

Here's my upload_to:

```
def file_path(instance, filename):
    extension = filename.split('.')[-1]
    new_filename = '%s - %s.%s' % (str(instance.model.object_number), str(instance.model.object_name), str(extension))
    return '/'.join(['files', str(instance.model.object_theme), str(instance.model.object_number), new_filename])
```

Comment: the function `file_path` should return a string.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can write your own `upload_to` function, as explained in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

If you want to avoid overwriting files with identical names, you have to add that functionality back. The default storage uses this function `django.core.file.storage.get_availble_name()` 
You can read the [source code on github](https://github.com/django/django/blob/56c461a0d7c1cbb9d5709bda817579c7ee18d474/django/core/files/storage.py#L65)

Edit: It looks as though your `upload_to` function doesn't return anything. It should return a pathname as a string.

```
import os
def file_path(instance, filename):
    base, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    return '{model.object_number} - {model.object_name}{extension}'.format(
        model=instance.model, extension=extension)
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I was already using a custom upload_to. That doesn't stop Django from altering filenames (and maybe folder names, haven't tested that). It's something that happens as a last step or something.

Comment: Really? What does your custom upload_to look like? What storage backend do you use? Version of django?

Comment: Well, not really sure what you mean with storage backend (quite new to Django), but I haven't changed a lot from default Django. It's django 1.9. The upload_to just uses some database info to create the folder structure and filename and then returns it. Nothing special at all...

Comment: I don't know why that should happen for you. I just tested it, and django doesn't do any changes to the file name when you use a custom `upload_to` function. If you use a string pattern for `upload_to`, or leave it with the default value, the filename is cleaned using the function `django.utils.text.get_valid_filename()`

Comment: You could try using `pdb.set_trace()` inside the upload_to function to step through the code and figure out when and how the file name string is converted.

Comment: Ah, `django.utils.text.get_valid_filename()` is editing my filename. I've looked at it and it does exactly what I don't want. Do you know of any way to skip the get_valid_filename() without making it impossible to use it anywhere else. I only want to skip it in this specific case...

Comment: Post your `upload_to` function and the `FileField` declaration in the question.

Comment: I've added it to the original question :)

Comment: Oops. I'm sorry, my function did return a string, I copied 1 line too few. See the return in my originial post. Thanks for your continious help though, I really appreciate it!

Comment: In that case I have no idea why this is happening, since I can't reproduce that behaviour. When changing the upload function, I can save files with brackets, spaces and unicode characters. You could try to make your own subclass of `model.Filefield` if you figure out what's going wrong. Or maybe try `upload = models.FileField(upload_to=lambda fn: fn)`, which should preserve the filename exactly as originally uploaded.

Comment: Well, that's... annoying. I'll take another look at it tomorrow. It's quite late now here. Again, thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your own storage class

## mystorage.py

```
import re

from django.utils.encoding import force_text
from django.utils.functional import keep_lazy_text
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage


@keep_lazy_text
def get_valid_filename(s):
    """
    >>> get_valid_filename(" tawanda's portrait in 2019.jpg ")
    'tawandas portrait in 2019.jpg'
    """
    s = force_text(s).strip()
    return re.sub(r'(?u)[^-\w. ]', '', s)


class CleanFileNameStorage(FileSystemStorage):
       
    def get_valid_name(self, name):
        """
        Return a filename, based on the provided filename, that's suitable for
        use in the target storage system.
        """
        return get_valid_filename(name)
```

If you want to apply this storage to all models you can assign the Django setting `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` with your custom class e.g

`DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'mystorage.CleanFileNameStorage'`

If this is only for a particular model then:

## models.py

```
def myfile_save_to(instance, filename):
    return 'my_files/{filename}'.format(filename=filename)


class MyFileModel(models.Model):
    my_file = models.FileField(
        upload_to=myfile_save_to,
        storage=CleanFileNameStorage(),
    )
```

Remember if you specify the storage on a model level you must initialize the class e.g. `CleanFileNameStorage()` if you don't you will get argument errors